# storing polymorphic objects in unordered_set

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-set

Say I have a Base class

```
struct Base {
    int x;
};
```

And I know there is a `Derived` class which derives from `Base`, but its definition is not available to me at this point (it exists in a downstream module).

Now I have a `unordered_set<Base*>` which will store a mixture of `Base` and `Derived` objects. If I don't specify a custom hash function, will this unordered_set work correctly (i.e. hash the elements by their actual type, so that two `Derived` objects with the same `x` but different in some other derived fields are treated as different)?

Assuming that I do need a custom hash function, since I don't have the definition of `Derived` yet, I wish to write my hash function as a virtual member function of `Base` so that `Derived` can simply override that function to perform its own hash when the `unordered_set` calls for it. Is this possible? Or is there some other preferred/established solution to this kind of problem?

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: I just edited my question so hopefully it's clearer now... having a working unordered_set is indeed what I want, though virtual hash function may not be the right solution to it.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you can do it in this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <memory>

struct Base {
    int x;

    virtual size_t hash() const {
        return std::hash<int>()(x);
    }
};

// just some Derived example
struct Derived : Base {
    int y;

    // performing hashing for a pair of integers
    virtual size_t hash() const override {
        return std::hash<int>()(x) ^ std::hash<int>()(y);
    }
};

struct Hasher {
    size_t operator()(const Base* ptr) const {
        return ptr->hash();
    }
};

struct CheckEq {
    bool operator()(Base* lhs, Base* rhs) const {
        auto dLhs = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(lhs);
        auto dRhs = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(rhs);

        // different types
        if ((dLhs == nullptr) != (dRhs == nullptr)) {
            return false;
        }

        // both Base
        if (dLhs == nullptr && dRhs == nullptr) {
            return lhs->x == rhs->x;
        }

        // both Derived
        return dLhs->x == dRhs->x && dLhs->y == dRhs->y;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::unordered_set<
        Base*,
        Hasher,  // struct with defined size_t operator()(const Base*) const, returning hash of object
        CheckEq  // struct with defined bool operator(const Base*, const Base*) const for additional checking whether 2 objects with same hashes are different
    > set;

    // checking if it works
    auto objBase1 = std::make_unique<Base>();
    objBase1->x = 5;
    auto objBase2 = std::make_unique<Base>();
    objBase2->x = 5;
    auto objBase3 = std::make_unique<Base>();
    objBase3->x = 6;

    auto objDerived1 = std::make_unique<Derived>();
    objDerived1->x = 5;
    objDerived1->y = 6;
    auto objDerived2 = std::make_unique<Derived>();
    objDerived1->x = 5;
    objDerived1->y = 6;
    auto objDerived3 = std::make_unique<Derived>();
    objDerived1->x = 50;
    objDerived1->y = 60;

    set.insert(objBase1.get());
    set.insert(objBase2.get());
    set.insert(objBase3.get());
    set.insert(objDerived1.get());
    set.insert(objDerived2.get());
    set.insert(objDerived3.get());

    std::cout << set.size() << std::endl;  // prints 4

    return 0;
}
```

*UPD.* It seems to me you need to store objects somewhere, so

```
std::unordered_set<
    std::unique_ptr<Base>,  // or shared_ptr
    Hasher,
    CheckEq
> set;
```

might be a better idea.